# Android launch dialog fragment from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have a fragment class which has action bar icon. It is like this -

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_call, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.call:
             //Call Dialog fragment from here
              CallDialogFragment dialog = CallDialogFragment .instantiate(getActivity(), "fragmentTAG");
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
                return false;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

**EDIT :**

```
public class CallDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public CallDialogFragment () {

    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.call_dialog_fragment, new LinearLayout(getActivity()), false);



        // Build dialog
        Dialog builder = new Dialog(getActivity());
        builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        builder.setContentView(view);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

TheDialogFragment class looks like this. I get error in my fragment saying Incompatible Types

How do I call a dialog fragment from a fragment

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html?m=1

Comment: I dont know why it was down voted... Still I dont have a convincing answer

Comment: "Incompatible Types Required: x.y.z.CallDialog Found: android.app.Fragment" tl;dr change `CallDialogFragment dialog = CallDialogFragment .instantiate(getActivity(), "fragmentTAG");
 ` to `DialogFragment dialog = new CallDialogFragment();`

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: from link `private void showEditDialog() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        EditNameDialog editNameDialog = new EditNameDialog();
        editNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
    }` is you use android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your Dialog Fragment like the following

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.call:
                //Call Dialog fragment from here
                CallDialogFragment dialog = new CallDialogFragment();
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");

                return true;

        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me in more detail

Comment: I've updated the answer. What have you done by far to show the DialogFragment?

Comment: See my edited question please...It is giving me error as incompatible types. Required CallDialogFragment Found:Fragment

Comment: Make sure to extends DialogFragment class in CallDialogFragment

Comment: Could you also show the CallDialogFragment class in your question?

Comment: Please see the EDIT in the question

Comment: Replace `getFragmentManager` with `getSupportFragmentManager`.

Comment: Are you using `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` or `android.app.DialogFragment` in CallDialogFragment?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "TAG");` where `dialogFragment` is an instance of your DialogFragment class, `"TAG"` is the string tag to identify your dialog in fragment manager.

Depending on whether your enclosing Fragment is the support library or standard Fragment, the `getFragmentManager()` will return either support or standard fragment manager.

If you need to obtain the fragment instance, that was previously attached, use the `findFragmentByTag()` method and cast to your dialog fragment class, for example:

```
((MyDialogFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG))...
```

Search by the tag that was previously used to attach / show the dialog fragment.

Comment: I did not understand